# An additive combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Given $n,m\in\Bbb N$.

We want to find two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that
$$|A|=|B|=n$$
$$\min\{a\in A,b\in B\}>m$$
$$|A+B|=2n$$ where $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$.

What is the minimum possible value for $\max\{a\in A,b\in B\}$?

Comment: The restriction $|A+B|=2n$ seems to suggest that $A$ and $B$ are close to being arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @Element118 what do you mean?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can set $m=0$ or $m=-1$ (whichever is more convenient) without loss of generality. After solving the reduced problem, you can add $m$ back to $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Consider $a_1<a_2<a_3<\dots<a_n$ and $b_1<b_2<b_3<\dots<b_n$
Then:
$a_1+b_1<a_1+b_2<a_1+b_3<\dots<a_1+b_n<a_2+b_n<a_3+b_n<\dots<a_n+b_n$. This shows that there are at least $2n-1$ elements in $A+B$. Equality occurs when $A$, $B$ are arithmetic progressions with the same common difference.

Comment: I went ahead and answered the question as asked. I'm guessing that you might also be interested in the case of $|A+B|=n^2$, but I don't know how to solve that one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're interested in nonempty sets, so $n\geq1$. The conditions $|A|=|B|=n$ and $|A+B|=2n$ further require $n\geq2$. I'll need this to define $B$.

The minimum possible value of $\max(A\cup B)$ is $m+n+1$. It is achieved (not uniquely) by $A=[m+1,m+n]$ and $B=[m+1,m+n-1]\cup\{m+n+1\}$, so that $A+B=[2m+2,2m+2n+1]$.

The only other possibility for the first two conditions is $A=B=[m+1,m+n]$, but then as Element118 noted, $|A+B|=2n-1$, which violates the third condition.